# Is "us" a valid language for the lang attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, attributes

In the example HTML file that comes with jQuery UI, the `html` element looks like this:

```
<html lang="us">
```

Is this even a valid language to use in the `lang` field? I thought it had to be `en` or similar? What kinds of things are valid? Would `en-US` or similar be valid if you wanted to specify US English? Are some values only compatible with some browsers or systems?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

Comment: language = American?  Just take zee colorful donuts and get outta here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even a valid language to use in the lang field?

No, it is not [an ISO language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

> Would en-US or similar be valid if you wanted to specify US English?

Yes

> Are some values only compatible with some browsers or systems?

Yes. For example, a screen reader might not have a pronunciation guide for `zu` available (so would revert to a default).

Comment: So is this a bug in jQuery UI to have this included?